# Not able to access Stack Overflow chat

Tags: support

I am unable to access the JavaScript chat room. I am getting the following error.

[image]

Is it because my company blocking it or is it something else?

There are no load failure in the network tab:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a javascript error - you should ask for help in the javascript roo.... Oh wait... ;-)

Comment: What is not loading, in the Network tab of the dev tools?

Comment: @Oded No failures, see edit 1 for picture

Comment: Did you try a hard refresh of the page? You may have a bad version of the script cached locally. Other things to try - connect over https, to rule out any MITM (man in the middle).

Comment: Can you try using `https://chat.stackoverflow.com`? Your corporate network could well be 'correcting perceived security vulnerabilities'.

Comment: Also, if there is an unexpected token in `master-chat.js`, look at the response information in the browser developer tools? Given that there is an unexpected token error in that file, that'd be the first place I'd look for any interference.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That works, it does not load only when I try to access the room

Comment: Talked to IT support team, its because of the security system they have here, it was replacing some texts in the script and was getting redirected to sstatic.net (not sure what that is). Got it fixed now